# Concatenate thousands of files already sorted and re-sort the output file quickly

Tags: memory, sort, out-of-memory

I have ~100000 files each of one with unique rows such as:

**File1.txt**

```
chr1_1_200  
chr1_600_800  
...
```

**File2.txt**

```
chr1_600_800  
chr1_1000_1200  
...
```

**File3.txt**

```
chr1_200_400    
chr1_600_800  
chr1_1000_1200  
...
```

Every file has around ~30 million rows and when its time to perform the command:

`cat *txt | sort -u > Unique_Position.txt`

the system runs out of memory. How can I handle this with normal command lines in Linux?

Comment: What operating system are you using; or, more pertinently, do you have GNU sort available? Also, are all the files sorted in a way that you like already? (noting that you'd need to carefully specify a sort key and field(s))

Comment: I am using Linux as an operating system and I have this GNU version:  ```which gcc --version
GNU which v2.20, Copyright (C) 1999 - 2008 Carlo Wood.
GNU which comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY;
This program is free software; your freedom to use, change
and distribute this program is protected by the GPL.
``` and the files are already sorted in the way I like yes..

Comment: First of all, there's no reason for `cat`. Just run `sort -u *txt > Unique_Position.txt`. Also, if your files are already sorted, please [edit] your question and mention that. It is a very important detail.

Comment: I'm sure you can get adequate advice here. However, there was also a lengthy thread that discussed finding the _sweet spot_ for a very long file, and your collection of files could be thought of a large file. That was about time; finally by tweaking the options on sort the time was decreased from a day to hours (21 -> 6). I have not thought about whether these problems are closely-enough similar to be of value to you, but you may want to peruse that thread ... good luck ... cheers, drl  || https://www.unix.com/unix-for-advanced-and-expert-users/252790-help-optimizing-sort-large-files.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files are already sorted in an acceptable way, you could merge-sort them and then `uniq` them:

```
sort -t_ -k2,2n -k3,3n -m -- *.txt | uniq > Unique_Position.txt
```

... which sorts numerically on the second field (as delimited by underscores `_`) and if those keys are unique, by the third field. The resulting output is then piped through `uniq` before being redirected into the output file.

Given the (short) sample input above, the results are:

```
chr1_1_200
chr1_200_400
chr1_600_800
chr1_1000_1200
```

---

If you're able to fully specify the sort fields for the lines that you want to keep, you could do it all within `sort` by adding the `-u` option:

```
sort -t_ -k1 -k2,2n -k3,3n -m -u *.txt > Unique_Position.txt
```

This would preserve unique lines among the three listed fields without needing to call out to `uniq` (notice the addition of the `-u` option).  These sort fields need to be match the way that the input files are sorted.

Comment: just to understand, the merge-sort is avoiding the memory issue? Just as a reminder I have ~100000 files and each one has 30 million positions.. The final output file will have approx 100 million positions/rows.

Comment: I don't have your environment (files & memory) so I can't say for sure; I wanted to provide an option that might work. Given that you have GNU sort available, if you run into memory constraints, adjust sort's `--batch-size=16` option upwards to see if you succeed.

Comment: I see the checkmark now; did it work as-is, or did you have to adjust --batch-size?

Comment: `-k2n,3n` doesn't make sense. ITYM `-k2,2n -k3,3n`.

Comment: See also the `-u` option of `sort` that will remove entries with duplicate sort key.

Comment: Thanks, @StéphaneChazelas; I've corrected the sort key. I had `sort ... -u` initially but wasn't keying on all of the fields (and so was potentially dropping lines). I'll add a note.

Comment: But then duplicate lines are not guaranteed to be consecutive as they're only sorted on part of the line. It would only work if the inputs were already sorted with `-k2,2n -k3,3n -k1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97892/discussion-between-jeff-schaller-and-stephane-chazelas).